# How to resolve Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running a rails3 app on Dreamhost: not the best call but I need it operational before I can pitch migrating to Heroku.

I am using rails 3.2.1, and ruby 1.8.7 with

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.7'

in my Gemfile...

I get the following error when I deploy and reload:

Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

I have tried gem 'mysql2', gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3' and get the exact same issue.

Any other ideas?

Comment: have you changed the "adapter:" line in your database.yml to adapter:mysql2?

Comment: cool, making it into a more proper answer

Answer (score 10):

First try adding `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to your `application.rb`.

Then make sure your DATABASE_URL var starts with mysql2:// instead of mysql://

Comment: Excellent. Fixing the DATABASE_URL did it for me.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I was using `mysql2` gem with `mysql2` adapter but it wasn't working then I changed the database url to start with `mysql2` and it worked fine!

Answer (score 5):

In general when rails is trying to be helpful it will try to generate the name of an adapter gem based on whatever you have in your database.yml. If that gem doesn't exist it's a good indication that something with the adapter line is wrong

for mysql2 the adapter type needs to be mysql2 as well

database.yml

```
adapter: mysql2
```

Comment: I have that set like that already.  what solved the issue for me is to actually add gem 'mysql' to the gmefile in addition to the mysql2 listing

Comment: You shouldn't need both mysql and mysql2 gems, your app should use one or the other.  Sounds like your app is reproducing this though https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5333

Comment: could be...  Not sure I know enough to say yes or no.  Has to be there or the remote server asks for the mysql-activerecord-adapter...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after checking if you have in database.yml that you have adapter:mysql2 you should check if you have the gem of mysql loaded.

in your Gemfile you should have the line : gem "mysql2" and not other database like sqlite3 which was my case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I get into the same situation of trying to set up mysql with Ruby on Rails for my 
Windows Vista platform installed with MySQL 5.5 and Rails Installer for Ruby 1.93.

After getting the adapter and connector for mysql2, I still get this error message : "rubygems_integration.rb:143:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2
 adapter:`gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the b
undle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)"

I checked the my gem directory "Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems" and see 
both activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3 and mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32 are there and
the database.yaml file is correctly updated.

The missing piece is here:http://www.mohanarun.com/how-to-install-mysql-adapter-ruby-gem-in-windows/

After restarting the MySQL server and update the gem file as stated in the above URL. It works.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: It's always good to cite references, but your answer would be more helpful if it actually described the fix given in the linked article.